# How can I make node wait before returning the document?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

When I retrieve a json Document I want to update an array of invitations. This array consist of _id values, which I want to update and set to the username. To do so I lookup the _id and find the corresponding username. However the array.push function finishes before the lookup of the corresponding username. And therefore an empty value is added. How can I make node wait to push only after the corresponding username was found.

```
exports.contactBoard = (req, res) => {
    const username = req.params.username;
    contactUsername = '';
    User.findOne({
        'username': username
    }).then(document => {
        document.invitationsFromFriends.forEach(element => {
            User.findById(element).then(document => {
                contactUsername = document.username;
                console.log("locatie 1" + contactUsername)
            })
        })
        console.log("locatie 2" + contactUsername)
        document.invitationsFromFriends.push(contactUsername);
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "retrieved user contacts",
            contacts: document
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Just move the `res.status(200).json(....)` call inside the `User.findById()`'s `.then()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `async-await` or `promise` to do this.

As the database request is executed asynchronously you will need to await till it returns for sending the response or send it from the callback of promise.

For Async-Await this could be a possible refactor:

```
exports.contactBoard = async (req, res) => {
...
const doc = await User.findOne({'username': username}).exec();

doc.invitationsFromFriends.forEach (async element =>
        const doc1 = await User.findById(element).exec()
          contactUsername = doc1.username;
          console.log("locatie 1" + contactUsername)
        }))
        console.log("locatie 2" + contactUsername)
        document.invitationsFromFriends.push(contactUsername);

res.status(200).json({
    message:"retrieved user contacts",
    contacts: document
})
```

For promise send the response from the callback: